# How to generate GloVe embeddings for POS tags? Python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, word-embedding

For a sentence analysis task, I would like to take the sequence of POS tags associated with the sentence and feed it to my model as if the POS tags are words.

I am using GloVe to make representations of each word in the sentence and SpaCy to generate POS tags. However, GloVe embeddings do not make much sense for POS tags. So I will have to somehow create embeddings for each POS tag. What is the best way to do create embeddings for POS tags, so that I can feed POS sequences into my model in the same way I would feed sentences? Could anyone point to code examples of how to do this with GloVe in Python?

**Added context**

My task is a binary classification of sentence pairs, based on their resemblance (similar meaning vs different meaning).

I would like to use POS tags as words, so that the POS tags serve as an additional bit of information to compare the sentences. My current model does not use an LSTM as a way to predict sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most word embedding models still rely on an underlying assumption that the meaning of a word is induced by its usage context. For example, learning a word2vec embedding with skipgram or continuous bag of words formulations implicitly assumes a model in which the representation vector of the word is based on the context words that co-occur with the target word, specifically by learning to create embeddings that best solve the classification task of distinguishing pairs of words that contextually co-occur from random pairs of words (so-called negative sampling).

But if the input is changed to be a sequence of discrete labels (POS tags), this assumption doesn't seem like it needs to remain accurate or reasonable. Part of speech labels have an assigned meaning that is not really induced by the context of being surrounded by other part of speech labels, so it's unlikely that standard learning tasks which are used to produce word embeddings would work when treating POS labels as if they were words from a much smaller vocabulary.

What is the overall sentence analysis task in your situation?

*Added after question was updated with the learning task at hand.*

Let's assume you can create POS input vectors for each sentence example. If there are N different POS labels possible, it means your input will consist of one vector from word embeddings and another vector of length N, where the value in component `i` represents the number of terms in the input sentence that possess POS label `P_i`.

For example, let's pretend the only POS labels possible are 'article', 'noun' and 'verb', and you have a sentence with ['article', 'noun', 'verb', 'noun']. Then this transforms into `[1, 2, 1]`, and probably you want to normalize it by the length of the sentence. Let's call this input `pos1` for sentence number 1 and `pos2` for sentence number 2.

Let's call the word embedding vector input for sentence 1 as `sentence1`. `sentence1` will be calculated by looking up each word embedding from a separate source, like a pretrained word2vec model or fastText or GloVe, and summing them up (using continuous bag of words). And the same for `sentence2`.

It's assumed that your batches of training data would already be processed into these vector formats, so a given single input would be a 4-tuple of vectors: the looked up CBOW embedding vector for sentence 1, same for sentence 2, and the calculated discrete representation vector for POS labels of sentence 1, and same for sentence 2.

A model that could work from this data might be like this:

```
from keras.engine.topology import Input
from keras.layers import Concatenate
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dense
from keras.models import Model


sentence1 = Input(shape=word_embedding_shape)
sentence2 = Input(shape=word_embedding_shape)
pos1 = Input(shape=pos_vector_shape)
pos2 = Input(shape=pos_vector_shape)

# Note: just choosing 128 as an embedding space dimension or intermediate
# layer size... in your real case, you'd choose these shape params
# based on what you want to model or experiment with. They don't mean
# anything here.

sentence1_branch = Dense(128)(sentence1)
sentence1_branch = Activation('relu')(sentence1_branch)
# ... do whatever other sentence1-only stuff

sentence2_branch = Dense(128)(sentence2)
sentence2_branch = Activation('relu')(sentence2_branch)
# ... do whatever other sentence2-only stuff

pos1_embedding = Dense(128)(pos1)
pos1_branch = Activation('relu')(pos1_embedding)
# ... do whatever other pos1-only stuff

pos2_embedding = Dense(128)(pos2)
pos2_branch = Activation('relu')(pos2_embedding)
# ... do whatever other pos2-only stuff


unified = Concatenate([sentence1_branch, sentence2_branch,
                       pos1_branch, pos2_branch])
# ... do dense layers, whatever, to the concatenated intermediate 
# representations

# finally boil it down to whatever final prediction task you are using, 
# whether it is predicting a sentence similarity score (Dense(1)), 
# or predicting a binary label that indicates whether the sentence 
# pairs are similar or not (Dense(2) then followed by softmax activation, 
# or Dense(1) followed by some type of probability activation like sigmoid).

# Assume your data is binary labeled for similar sentences...
unified = Activation('softmax')(Dense(2)(unified))
unified.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', other parameters)

# Do training to learn the weights...


# A separate model that will just produce the embedding output
# from a POS input vector, relying on weights learned from the
# training process.
pos_embedding_model = Model(inputs=[pos1], outputs=[pos1_embedding])
```

Comment: Thanks! I will update my question a bit based on your question.

Comment: Based on your update and design choice not to use LSTM-like architectures, then I think my suggestion of providing the summation of one-hot encoded POS discrete label vectors as an input is one good option. It loses spatial structure of the POS tags, but it seems like your model is making that tradeoff anyway.

Comment: Yes, I will give it a try!

Comment: @twhale I added some Keras pseudocode based on my understanding of the particular task you're working on. My example code likely is not exactly right for your specific task or data, but it should help with the idea, especially if you want to use the final step where I create an extra `Model` object to output the POS embeddings after training has completed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very interesting. I am a relative novice so It may be a bit too advanced for me to implement on my own. But I do understand it and it makes a lot of sense. Thank you!